# I want to traverse a nested list and find index of that list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I want to traverse over the nested list below, search for a number and then print the index value of that entire list, i.e: `my_foo(lst=[1, 3, 'Test', 5, 7], number=3)` returns `1`.

This is my list:

```
my_list = [['Hello', 'World','!'], [1, 3, 'Test', 5, 7], [2, 4]]
```

I want to search for example 1, and if that's True, print its list index.

Comment: Does `print(my_list.index([1, 3, 'Test', 5, 7]))` not fit your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that takes a list and a function as a key:

```
from typing import List, Callable

my_list = [['Hello', 'World','!'],[1, 3, 'Test', 5, 7],[2, 4]]


def nested_index(l: List, key: Callable[[List], bool]):
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        if key(v):
            return i
    raise ValueError
```

Example:

```
nested_index(my_list, lambda l: 1 in l) -> 1
nested_index(my_list, lambda l: "hello" in l) -> 0
nested_index(my_list, lambda l: "foo" in l) -> ValueError
```